# Ask Ubuntu login needs improving

Tags: discussion, login

Why does Ask Ubuntu have such a terrible login method?  Surely there are better ways to organise a site and keep it "safe".  {e.g.  make the "Log In" at top of page larger and more accessible / legible /findable, or re-think the actual login page once that has been found).  This is not a criticism, I think Ask Ubuntu contributors do a wonderful job - I would hope constructive critique is acceptable?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to say here - what do you mean by "safe"? I don't see why the 'login' link should be made larger - the most basic functions of the site - asking and answering questions do not require logging in, and if you do something which does requires logging in (like voting) you'll be prompted to do so. You also mentioned something about the OpenID selection page, but you haven't mentioned what's wrong with it, only that it needs "re-think", which isn't very helpful

Comment: Interesting. However, when, I have "asked" I have been prompted to login first.  The login link at the top of the page is [to me] very small and was far from easy to see on my first visit.  I do wear specs but I am not normally bewildered looking for a site's login link - I therefore think it must be an awful experience for those with sight impairment.  The login page itself is laid out in a less than logical way.  I was not, at the time - logged in to Launchpad [or Open-id] yet both links [LP & Open_Id] seemed to to suggest by their presence that I could click them and login at the same time.

Comment: [and thanks for doing the migration of the question for me ;)

Comment: Honestly ,I am an askubuntuser because I can  easily login via fb id , I did'nt joined in ubuntu fourums  or other services only because to avoid login headache :)

Answer (score 7):

I, for one, like that the focus is not on registering before you can use askubuntu. There are pleny of websites/forums that force me to register only to show me a site that is not worth looking at for longer than 10 seconds.

<sub>I would be more happy if the login would work on my PS3 though.</sub>

Comment: heh, +1 we need it working on your PS3. I'll file a `priority:lolwat` bug on that. ;)

Comment: the images you need to click (like the google one) never show up on my PS3 ;)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62159/why-can-i-no-longer-use-the-ps3-web-browser-on-stack-overflow

Comment: webkit is no longer possible @YiJiang ;)